# Page not found on webserver in my raspberry pi

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, webserver, raspberry-pi

I wrote a simple rest api few weeks ago, this api working good into my webserver (bitnami - localhost), and also to my pay hosting.
Now I setup a webserver with the raspberry, I'm a linux newbie and I bought a raspberry for learn. Anyway, the webserver working perfectly but when I have uploaded my rest api I got:

```
The request Url /project/api/v1/user/getUsers was not found on this server
Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Server at webserver Port 80
```

in this way I perform the request:

```
http://webserver/project/api/v1/user/getUsers
```

now this api shunk the request from index.php that load the properly php file by a router, in this case user.php -> getUsers (function)

this roles is available in the .htaccess that have this content:

```
RewriteEngine On

#basic roles

RewriteBase /api/v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Shunk request on index.php 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now I guess that my webserver have a problem with this .htaccess, 'cause if I type this url:

```
http://webserver/project/api/v1/
```

I can see correctly the index.php response of:

> Invalid Request

from my own rest api

any idea about this? Thanks.

Update

seems that the .htaccess is readed correctly but cannot found the index.php page, strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the content of RewriteBase should be:

```
RewriteBase /project/api/v1/
```

I would also suggest you to check your current setting of DocumentRoot to see if it is pointing to your www folder.

You can further check the link below as reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase